# Firebase Message Notification

Tags: firebase, flutter

I try to send notification from Firebase to phone but I had a problem when I try it. I tried a lot of things to fix
this problem:

[image]

in Android Studio.

This is in Xcode:

this is AppDelegate:
[image]

this is problem:
[image]

This is the link of this code: `https://github.com/tult1803/flutter.git`

Answer (score 0):

I also have the warning in the app delegate swift. It doesn't cause a problem.

You shouldn't edit "GeneratedPluginRegistrant". It's not in the guide.

Be sure to follow the exact steps on the info page on the package. You're using flutter, so you only need to do the steps the readme describes. Make sure to do every single step!

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab-

Make sure to install the package first.